# Count down clock resets

Tags: javascript

I have a count down clock on my site but it resets if you clear your browser history. Is there a way to stop this from happening. I found the code on a website that you can download from. I was not expecting it to reset when you clear your browser history. Can this code be modified or would it be better for me to find another code for it.

Thanks

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 100;
text-align: center;
}

#clockdiv > div {
background: #0294cb;
border-radius: 3px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px;
}

#clockdiv div > span {
background: #42baff;
border-radius: 3px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
}

.smalltext {
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
<div>
<span class="days"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="hours"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="seconds"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed it resets even when you refresh your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the initial deadline time in localStorage(But this will get cleared on erasing history) and then use that instead of resetting it again on reload, If you want your timer to not reset when clearing data, you will have to maintain a server side state.

Comment: How would I maintain a server side state. Thanks

Comment: @jessiewilliams That would depend on what server you are using and whether you have any backend code

Answer (score 0):

You can add this piece of code to the bottom of your script. Instead of initializing new deadline each time, you check whether the deadline has already been initialized and stored in `localStorage`, if so then fetch the deadline from it. If no, the create the new deadline like you did in your original code and store it in `localStorage`.

Note that you need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` methods if you want to store and later retrieve an object from `localStorage` because it can only hold strings and default string representation of an object isn't very useful.

This code will not reset the countdown on page reload and you can clean history as well but you can't clear `localStorage` (cached files and cookies) for it to work.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('deadline')) {
  const deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  localStorage.setItem('deadline', JSON.stringify(deadline));
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
} else {
  const deadline = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('deadline'));
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
}
```

See the snippet for full code, but note that it will not work here because `localStorage` is not accessible on SO. You will need to copy and paste it and test it in your browser.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


if (!localStorage.getItem('deadline')) {
  const deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  localStorage.setItem('deadline', JSON.stringify(deadline));
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
} else {
  const deadline = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('deadline'));
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
}
```

```css
#clockdiv {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

#clockdiv > div {
  background: #0294cb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
}

#clockdiv div > span {
  background: #42baff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.smalltext {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
<div>
<span class="days"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="hours"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="seconds"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That one works for refreshing your page. But if you clear browser history it resets. Thanks

Comment: @jessiewilliams Well, you can clear browsing history and it will still work, but yes, if you clear cookies and cached data then it will fail and in such case it is impossible to achieve it via frontend. You would need server side application to hold the deadline.

Comment: @jessiewilliams That is really broad question. First you need to choose a technology/framework (e.g. node.js-express/python - django/php), then you need to actually set up that server. And then you need to code your server side application. It can be done quite quickly if you know how but it requires some knowledge. If you are interested in it then you can check e.g. tutorial on `node.js` and `express` framework which will show you how to do that.

Comment: I dont understand javascript. I just learned php. Is there anywhere online I could post the job for cheap. Thanks

Comment: @jessiewilliams Certainly there is, but I don't know where. But if you know php then it should be easy for you since you can do it with php as well, you just need to check how to set up a server running php.